# Get gen_fsm PID

Tags: erlang, pid, gen-fsm

I start gen_fsm:

```
start_link() ->
     gen_fsm:start_link({global, ?MODULE}, [],
                   []).
```

How can i get it's PID?

Thank you.

Comment: Please read the documentation before asking simple questions like this, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you check the [documentation](http://erldocs.com/R14B02/stdlib/gen_fsm.html?i=12&search=gen_fsm#start_link/3) for `gen_fsm:start_link/3` you'll see that it returns `{ok, Pid}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either get it as the result of gen_fsm:start_link/3 or since it is a registered process using whereis(nameofprocess).